# Is there a way to insert Javascript code exclusive for "grunt build"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm building an application with AngularJS and Grunt, and i have a particular line of code that i would like to use only in the "dist" version of my app, is there a way to tell grunt to delete that line of code unless i run 'grunt build'?

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize'
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

   /** Insert code if 'grunt build' **/
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  /** End of code inserted for build **/
```

}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a task like grunt-string-replace (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-string-replace) and then simply leave a comment in then replace that comment with what you want on build.

```
options: {
  replacements: [{
    pattern: '// insert code here',
    replacement: '$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);'
  }]
}
```